# How many ways can these ten books be put in order on a shelf?

Tags: combinatorics

> A librarian has $4$ identical copies of Hamlet,
>       $3$ identical copies of Macbeth, $2$ identical copies of Romeo and Juliet,
>       and $1$ copy of Midsummer's Night Dream. In how many distinct arrangements can these ten books be put in order on a shelf?
>
> 1. $720$
> 2. $1.512$
> 3. $2.520$
> 4. $6.400$
> 5. $12.600$

Hi. I am working with counting and I don't really know how to solve this question.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: We have $10$ books, thus $10!$ possible arrangements. There is no difference between books of the same kind, thus we have to divide by all inner arrangements of those books, hence in total we have $\displaystyle \frac{10!}{4!\cdot{3!}\cdot{2!}}=12600$ possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can arrange the books in $10!$ ways. But for each way of these $10!$ you can know permute the identical books and the arrangement will not change. This means division and gives the result
$$\frac{10!}{4!3!2!1!}=12600$$ The important step to solve this problem is to understand that it fits to the category: permutations with repetition.

Comment: Why do you divide with 4! * 3! * 2! and 1!

Comment: Because we need to consider for repetitions, and this is done by dividing the permutation by the factorial of the number of objects that are identical. $4$ identical Amlet's corresponds to $4!$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

That would be $\dfrac{10!}{4!3!2!1!}$ ways to arrange the books on the shelf, and for example $10! = 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdots 2\cdot 1$.